# Different document root for different sites with MAMP?

Tags: mamp

I have 2 sites in separate folders. Both sites need to be in the web root so I frequently need to change the document root in my MAMP settings. Im assuming the answer is no, but is there a way i can make both sites act as if they are in the web root? Are there any other general practice solutions to my issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/)

Add to **httpd.conf** something similar:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.tld
ServerAlias domain.tld *.domain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/site1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.otherdomain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/site2
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/vhosts_mamp.php